# Json array Dictionary parse nil in swift 5

Tags: swift

I have a json like bellow ..

```
 {"type": "Polygon","coordinates":[[[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813],[90.4018551231959,23.708188760430843],[90.40247361862504,23.7091957460091],[90.40143983815886,23.70975584674032],[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813]]]}
```

I have used bellow code to parse which returns nil

```
let json = myjsonString as? [String: Any]
```

But it returns nil. please help me to parse above json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deserialize the string, either with `JSONSerialization` or – more comfortable – with `JSONDecoder`

```
let jsonString = """
 {"type": "Polygon","coordinates":[[[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813],[90.4018551231959,23.708188760430843],[90.40247361862504,23.7091957460091],[90.40143983815886,23.70975584674032],[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813]]]}
"""

struct Overlay : Decodable {
    let type : String
    let coordinates : [[[Double]]]
}

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Overlay.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

At first, you need to convert data from your input string then you can convert data to dictionary object. You can try this example.

```
let jsonText = "{\"first_name\":\"Sergey\"}" 
var dictonary:NSDictionary?
if let data = jsonText.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) { 
    do {
       dictonary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
       if let myDictionary = dictonary { 
       print(" First name is: \(myDictionary["first_name"]!)") 
      } 
  } catch let error as NSError { 
     print(error) 
  } 
}
```